# R- xy scatter plot in 3d using density

Tags: r, plot

I want to visualize an x-y scatter in 3d, using the density/overlaps as z values.  I guess this would be like using alpha as a z-axis - more overlap = higher z.  Suggestions?  Perhaps using cloud() in lattice library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a variety of 2d density functions available:

```
MASS::kde2d
fields::smooth.2d
hexbin::hexbin
```

In general visualizing 3d clouds of points is rather difficult. Pseudo 3d with surfaces is ok but the points do not display with sufficient depth cues. If you really want to try it, then use the `rgl` package so you can rotate.

Comment: +1.  thanks!  I agree...the type of visualization I'm proposing is difficult.  I'll take a look at rgl

Answer (score 6):

I use `rgl` for 3D visualization. You can rotate the image in rgl window using your mouse. Wheel zooms in/out.

```
example(plot3d)
rgl.bg(color = "black") # Space, the final Frontier.
```

[image]

Comment: +1...the comment made me laugh.  Awarding answer to @DWin because he posted about rgl first, but I appreciated the visual.