# 3D density plot (from 3D scatter plot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, plotly, density-plot

I am looking to generate a 3D density plot, with opacity depicting density within a region (for example, regions of high density displaying dark red and low density transparent light red). Something similar to the 2D graphs on this page; https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/2d-density-chart.html

As another layer of difficulty, I want the color depicting density to change depending on a label (in this case cell type). But I am actually having a really hard time finding the appropriate means to just generate a 3D density plot. Any suggestions?

I crossed this in Wolfram language; https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot3D.html but I am hoping to use R for my means.

As an example to work with, see below made with plotly

```
set.seed(123)
gene_x <- rnorm(500, mean=280, sd=100)
gene_y <- rnorm(500, mean = 450, sd=150)
gene_z <- rnorm(500, mean = 340, sd=80)
celltype1 <- data.frame(gene_x,gene_y,gene_z)
celltype1['celltype'] = "neuron"
gene_x <- rnorm(400, mean= 60, sd=150)
gene_y <- rnorm(400, mean = 40, sd=100)
gene_z <- rnorm(400, mean = 110, sd=50)
celltype2 <- data.frame(gene_x,gene_y,gene_z)
celltype2['celltype'] = "astrocyte"
df <- rbind(celltype1,celltype2)

library("plotly")
plot_ly(x=df$gene_x, y=df$gene_y, z=df$gene_z, type="scatter3d", mode="markers", color = df$celltype, marker = list(size = 4))
```

Comment: 3d density scatter might be hard.. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972527/r-xy-scatter-plot-in-3d-using-density

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rgl` package to get a 3d plot.  On your dataframe `df` the following code:

```
library(rgl)
mycolor <- c("red", "blue")
open3d()
plot3d(x=df$gene_x, y=df$gene_y, z=df$gene_z, size=4, col=mycolor )
```

gives this output:

[image: output]

Please check out the `rgl` package for further enhancement according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. My code already gives me a 3D plot. I am specifically looking for a 3D heatmap or contour plot.